# How can I get constraint definition in SAP HANA?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, hana

I want to get a list of contraint definition in my schema.
F.e. in postrge we can get from pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid, true)
or in Oracle from DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl (object_type => 'INDEX',name => AI.INDEX_NAME, schema => AI.OWNER)

Is there any options to get it from SAP HANA?

Answer (score 2):

SAP HANA provides [system views](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/3859e48180bb4cf8a207e15cf25a7e57.html) to retrieve this kind of information. In your case, you should have a look at system view [CONSTRAINTS](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/209f7cf5751910149d9ce6b033d8ddce.html).